# How to fix RecordNotFound error when creating a record in Active Admin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, activeadmin

I have a registration app which registers a `Participant`, which then can be placed in a `Group` with other participants. I am using ActiveAdmin to assign them to groups.

When I try to create a new group using active admin I get the following error:

> "ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in Admin::GroupsController#create" with
>   this additional information: "Couldn't find all Participants with
>   'id': (0, 0) (found 0 results, but was looking for 2)"

I thought that perhaps it was because I had not generated a controller for my model yet.  However, when ran a generation for the controller I received this error:

```
identical  app/controllers/groups_controller.rb
  route  get 'groups/index'
  route  get 'groups/show'
  route  get 'groups/update'
  route  get 'groups/edit'
  route  get 'groups/create'
  route  get 'groups/new'
  invoke  erb
  exist    app/views/groups
  identical    app/views/groups/new.html.erb
  identical    app/views/groups/create.html.erb
  identical    app/views/groups/edit.html.erb
  identical    app/views/groups/update.html.erb
  identical    app/views/groups/show.html.erb
  identical    app/views/groups/index.html.erb
  invoke  test_unit
  identical    test/controllers/groups_controller_test.rb
  invoke  helper
  The name 'GroupsHelper' is either already used in your application or reserved by Ruby on Rails. Please choose an alternative and run this generator again.
```

My app folder contains all the necessary files though, so I added `@group = Group.new` to the `groups_controller`.

Here are my models:

```
# participant.rb
class Participant < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :volunteer_detail, :dependent => :destroy, inverse_of: :participant
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :volunteer_detail,   :allow_destroy => :true

  has_one :student_detail, :dependent => :destroy, inverse_of: :participant
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :student_detail,   :allow_destroy => :true
  has_and_belongs_to_many :groups, join_table: :matchups

  validates :last_name, presence: true
  # validates :gender, inclusion: { in: %w(male female) }
  validates :phone, presence: true
end

# group.rb
class Group < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :participants, join_table: :matchups
end
```

Here is my active admin resource file for group:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Group do
  permit_params :description , participant_ids: []
  form do |f|       
    f.inputs 'Group Details' do
    f.input :description
    f.input :participant_ids, as: :check_boxes, collection: Participant.pluck_all(:first_name, :last_name, :gender, :role, :id )
  end
end
```

I'm looking to create a new `Group` record using a form in ActiveAdmin, which utilizes records from an associated model, `Participant`.

Currently I am getting a RecordNotFound error. This could be due to problems with the controller, but I am unsure of how to remedy the issue caused during generation of the controller, or if that is even the problem.

Any insight into my problem would be appreciated.

Comment: what if use Participant.pluck(:f_name, :id) for a collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue isn't related to GroupsController. ActiveAdmin resource has nothing to do with it. The problem is in input for participant_ids. If you check generated html, you can see blank value in options. Should be:

```
f.input :participants, as: :check_boxes, collection: Participant.pluck(:first_name, :id )
```

In this case you have `first_name` as label and `id` as value, and all goes well. If you want a complex label (:first_name, :last_name, :gender, :role), you need to create a separate method in the Group model:

```
def label_for_admin
  first_name + last_name + gender + role
end

f.input :participants, as: :check_boxes, collection: Participant.pluck(:label_for_admin, :id )
```

Comment: Thanks, this does remove the error, and allow active admin to create the record, however now the :participant records which are checked are not being recorded to the record- when checking in the console, participant_id is listed as nil. Any ideas what might be happening? Here is the console data: `[#<Group id: 4, description: "test1", participant_id: nil, created_at: "2019-02-01 02:43:18", updated_at: "2019-02-01 02:43:18">]`

Comment: Group `has_and_belongs_to_many : participants `, it means, that all info about associated participants is stored in a separate `matchups` table (btw, not a best name for it). You can remove `participant_id` from groups table, because it is needed only for `belongs_to participant` association. You should check `Group.last.participant_ids` or `Group.last.participants`. `participant_ids` method is generated automatically from association name

Comment: Thanks, this solved the problem and made it very easy to understand This is my first Rails app and I'm learning as I go. If I want to view the group_id of each participant that is assigned to a `Group` when I view `Participant` record in the ActiveAdmin, how should I list it as a permitted param `Participant` resource for ActiveAdmin?

Comment: Happy to help you :) If you want only view group_ids, you don't need add it to permitted params. If you want to assign groups to participants, it should be `group_ids: []`

Comment: If I am looking at the `Participant` resource page in ActiveAdmin, only it's native attributes  appear, not any of it's nested attributes. Adding `group_ids: [ ]` to the Participant.rb params doens't change that. Am I misunderstanding it?

Comment: @dbate, yes, permit_params are not related to index/show of resources. Check [info about columns in docs](https://activeadmin.info/3-index-pages/index-as-table.html#defining-columns). Should be something like `column 'Groups' { |participant| participant.groups.map(&:title) }`